# Firefox is not showing desktop notifications if more than one is sent at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement desktop notifications for my application. It works fine if one notification is sent, however when more than one is sent at the same time, firefox does not display any of them. This problem is not present with Chrome.

Is this something that is just not possible with firefox? I was under the impression that the usage of tags inside the notification options were used for stacking notifications.

Code:

```
function isNewNotificationSupported() {
  if (!window.Notification || !Notification.requestPermission) return false;
  if (Notification.permission == "granted") throw new Error("");
  try {
    new Notification("");
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.name == "TypeError") return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function notifyMe(aa, bb, cc, dd) {
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    //alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  } else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    if (!document.hasFocus() || cc == 1) {
      var options = {
        body: bb,
        icon: "",
        dir: "ltr",
        tag: dd
      };
      var notification = new Notification(aa, options);

      notification.onshow = function() {
        setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), 15000);
      };
    }
  } else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    if (isNewNotificationSupported()) {
      Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
        if (!("permission" in Notification)) {
          Notification.permission = permission;
        }

        if (permission === "granted") {
          var options = {
            body: bb,
            icon: "",
            dir: "ltr",
            tag: dd
          };
          var notification = new Notification(aa, options);

          notification.onshow = function() {
            setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), 15000);
          };
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

notifyMe("New notification1","newtest","1","test1");
notifyMe("New notification2","newtest2","1","test2");
```

I created a jsfiddle for it at:

http://jsfiddle.net/1bm0wyvf/

**Update:** I think i solved it now by changing one of the notifyMe's to:

```
setTimeout(function() { notifyMe("Newnotification1","newtest","1","test1"); }, 200);
```

Firefox properly stacks them now.

Comment: On OS X I am seeing both. Shortly after the first one is shown, then text is updated to the second one.

Comment: I am using firefox on windows 8.1 where none are shown. If it works for you, then it seems that firefox on OS X works differently, but in your case (from what i read from your comment) it's still not stacking them like it does on Chrome.

Comment: That's true, but I don't think the OS X notifications center will stack multiple notifications from the same app. I believe it will only show them in sequence, although they will be in the list in notification center. You might be better off only showing one at a time.

Comment: Since `notification.onshow = function () { setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), 15000); }` creates closure and closure always keeps the latest value of the variables (in a nutshell) this is hapenning (in this case the variables for second notification). Try to cancel the closure here, it should be alright.

Comment: I added that part specifically for chrome, since firefox already closes notifications on its own. However even when i completely remove the closure blocks, it still does not work on firefox (windows 8.1). However, it seems it is a firefox.windows combination, since someone I asked with linux/firefox sees both notifications.

Comment: You can track bug report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1263155).

Comment: @Sempiterna I came across the exact same issue, have you ever resolved this issue ?

Comment: @Sempiterna, could you post if you resolve the issue? I also have this problem

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following function and it behave very well on Firefox/Linux.

```
function notif(message){

 if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
        Notification.permission = permission
      }
      if (permission === "granted") {
          let notification = new Notification(message)
      }
    })
  }
}
notif("Hello world!!")
```

[image]